# GPS module accuracy query

Tags: rf, gps

I have a GPS module with an accuracy of 1.5m + 1 ppm.

Query: What is meant by 1 ppm accuracy, what does it symbolize?

Comment: Could you provide a link to a datasheet?

Comment: ppm is part per million, it is a fractional error bound if no units are obvious.  In this case like Spehro says below it refers to the distance to the true or visualised differential base station.

Comment: In all the GPS module datasheet you can find that term

Answer (score 3):

That's a specification used in differential GPS, ppm refers to the added error as a proportion of the distance from the base station.

Comment: Means if I move 2km from base station then added error will 2km* 1?

Comment: 1ppm of 2km is 2mm.